# ¿Cómo remover un solo elemento de un vector? en R

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de escribir una función que genere un vector numérico que contenga todos los elementos de otro vector y los ordene al azar, pero de tal forma que dos elementos consecutivos NO sean iguales.

Tengo específicamente 2 problemas:

1. No logro remover el elemento del vector originario copiado en el vector receptor, teniendo en cuenta que cada elemento del vector generado debe estar en la misma cantidad que el original, y hay más de un elemento del mismo valor dentro dell vector original. 
   Por ejemplo: `x<-c(1,2,3,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,4)` como vector original. 
            `y<-sample(x,1)`              elemento al azar de ese vector
   quiero eliminar el elemento "y" de "x" SOLO UNA VEZ.
2. Luego como incorporar el elemento "y" a un nuevo vector "z", sin que el elemento "y" sea igual al elemento anterior en "z".
   Por ejemplo: `z<-append(z,y)`   como vector receptor del elemento "y" proveniente                  -                             de "x".
   cómo condicionar que ese elemento se incorpore a z solo si es diferente del anterior, y que haga un resampleo de "x" buscando un elemento que sea diferente.

De antemano MUCHAS GRACIAS por sus ayudas, soy muy nuevo en R (1 semana) y tengo varias limitaciones de lenguaje.

Esto es lo que llevo de la función:

```
 listarandom2<-function(x=c(0.24,0.60,0.10,0.06),n=100){
  finalist<-c()
  interlist<-c()
  randomlist<-c()
  longlist<-c()
  list<-c(1,10,2,20,3,30,4,40,5,50,6,60,7,70,8)
  prop<-x
  for(i in 1:15){ #//genera una lista de números que se distribuyan en la proporción indicada
    if(i==1||i==2){
      longlist<-append(longlist,rep(list[i],prop[1]*n/2))
    }
    else if(i==3||i==4||i==5||i==6||i==7||i==8||i==9||i==10||i==11||i==12){
      longlist<-append(longlist,rep(list[i],prop[2]*n/10))
    }
    else if(i==13||i==14){
      longlist<-append(longlist,rep(list[i],prop[3]*n/2))
    }
    else if(i==15){
      longlist<-append(longlist,rep(list[i],prop[4]*n))
    }
  } 
  for(i in 1:n){#//genera lista seleccionando elementos en forma aleatoria de longlist revisando que elemento siguiente no se repita
x<-sample(a,1)
if(x==f[i]){
    y<-setdiff(a,x)
    z<-sample(y,1)
    f<-append(f,z)
}
else{
    f<-append(f,x)
}... este loop me genera un vector "f" con elementos aleatorios de un vector "a" en que cada elemento es siempre diferente al inmediatamente anterior... pero no me permite que el vector "f" contenga exactamente los mismos elementos de "a" ya que en cada loop hace un RE-sampleo de "a" completo y no de "a" sin el elemento ya agregado previamente a "f".
```

}
      }
    }

Comment: Tendrás que mostrar algo del código que has intentado usar para resolver tus problemas. Si no muestras algo de código no podemos darte mucha ayuda.

Comment: Ahí agregué lo que llevo de código en la función (no está terminada porque aún no logro descifrar cómo escribir lo que me falta)

Comment: for(i in 1:length(a)){
    x<-sample(a,1)
    if(x==f[i]){
        y<-setdiff(a,x)
        z<-sample(y,1)
        f<-append(f,z)
    }
    else{
        f<-append(f,x)
    }
}

Esto me permite generar un vector "f" que agregue en forma aleatoria elementos del vector "a" y que no se repitan elementos consecutivos... PERO aún no logro eliminar el elemento sacado del vector "a", para así asegurar que los elementos de "f" sean iguales a los de "a".

Comment: Que significa la palabra "resampleo"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te voy a ayudar con la estructura básica, la automatización o implementación en un bucle te lo dejo a vos.

```
#Supongamos este es tu vector x de valores
#Estas 2 lineas ejectuas una sola vez (sería la inicializacion)
x <- c(100,25,31,18,39,43,55,64,72,81,45, 100)
z <- vector()

#En un bucle podrías hacer algo así:

#Muestreo de x un valor
y <- sample(x,1)
y

#Esto te devuelve la posición del valor y en x es solo un chequeo
#Si hay varios valores y en x te devuelve la posición del primero q aparece
match(y,x) 

#Chequeas que lo que vas a agregar a z no sea el ultimo que agregaste en z
if(z[length(z)] != y) {

  z <- append(z,y)  

} 
#por el lado del else podrías resamplear de x o sino dejalo que pase a la
#siguiente iteración
```

PD: El titulo de la pregunta no me parece adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

### Consideraciones

> *Esta pregunta podría no tener solución dependiendo la naturaleza de los datos de entrada para la implementación que se va ha desarrollar en esta respuesta, pero los conceptos son útiles también en machine learning - ML*

Lo anterior se debe a que en última instancia se busca `permutar` los elementos de un vector, esto equivale a barajar los naipes (`shuffle` el termino en inglés) o como un bingo o lotería extraer los números sin que estos vuelvan al ánfora (extracción sin reposición). Acá está más detallado [Variables aleatorias discretas y graficar su función de probabilidad acumulada en R](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/236850/variables-aleatorias-discretas-y-graficar-su-funci%c3%b3n-de-probabilidad-acumulada-e)

Esto último `R` base lo contempla con la función `sample`.

Si los elementos fueran `c(1,1,1,1,1,1)`, estadísticamente hablando no se estaría contraviniendo nada de lo mencionado anteriormente, pero como la restricción es que no sean iguales los elementos adyacentes... **el modelo que se plantea no podría solucionarlo**.

### Función Sample

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente vector y por un momento olvidemos la restricción de que los adyacentes sean iguales:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,4)
```

Digamos que sale `5` en nuestro sorteo... ya quedan `10`, sacamos otro y sale `2` nos quedan `9`... y así sucesivamente

Esto implica que no se van a reemplazar los elementos que se extraen, en tal sentido se puede emplear la función `sample` de la siguiente forma:

```
a <- sample(x, replace=FALSE)
a # es una permutacion de x
# 3 4 4 1 3 2 8 5 7 1 6
```

### Adyacentes diferentes

Observando la permutación `3 4 4 1 3 2 8 5 7 1 6` se evidencia que `4 4` no satisface la restricción de adyacentes diferentes.

Si se hiciera lo siguiente:

```
# a    3  4  4  1  3  2  8  5  7  1  6 (este ultimo '6' no entra en la resta)
# b(-) 4  4  1  3  2  8  5  7  1  6    (se desfasa en 1 el vector a y se omite el primero '3')
#-----------------------------------
#     -1  0  3 -2  1 -6  3 -2  6 -5
```

El vector `-1  0  3 -2  1 -6  3 -2  6 -5` contiene `cero` y se verifica que los adyacentes son iguales. Por tal motivo descartamos esta permutación y buscamos otra hasta encontrar la que satisfaga la restricción de adyacentes diferentes....

Acá la implementación

```
x <- c(1,2,3,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,4)
x_len <- length(x)

check_zero <- TRUE

while (check_zero){
  a <- sample(x, replace=FALSE)
  b <- a[2:x_len]        # el desfase de 1
  print(a); print(b)

  check_zero <- a[1:x_len-1] - b # el ultimo elemento de "a" no entra en la resta
  print(check_zero)

  check_zero <- 0 %in% check_zero # si el cero está los adyacentes son iguales
  cat("Sí hay cero continua iteracion:", check_zero,"\n\n")
}

cat("\nResultado\n")
print(a)
```

Al correr el código de arriba se obtiene la siguiente posible permutación

```
# [1] 3 4 4 1 3 2 8 5 7 1 6
# [1] 4 4 1 3 2 8 5 7 1 6
# [1] -1  0  3 -2  1 -6  3 -2  6 -5
#Sí hay cero continua iteracion: TRUE 

# [1] 7 3 4 4 2 5 1 3 8 6 1
# [1] 3 4 4 2 5 1 3 8 6 1
# [1]  4 -1  0  2 -3  4 -2 -5  2  5
#Sí hay cero continua iteracion: TRUE 

# [1] 7 3 2 5 6 8 4 4 1 1 3
# [1] 3 2 5 6 8 4 4 1 1 3
# [1]  4  1 -3 -1 -2  4  0  3  0 -2
#Sí hay cero continua iteracion: TRUE 

# [1] 7 1 3 5 3 1 2 4 4 8 6
# [1] 1 3 5 3 1 2 4 4 8 6
# [1]  6 -2 -2  2  2 -1 -2  0 -4  2
#Sí hay cero continua iteracion: TRUE 

# [1] 7 4 1 6 4 2 5 8 3 1 3
# [1] 4 1 6 4 2 5 8 3 1 3
# [1]  3  3 -5  2  2 -3 -3  5  2 -2
#Sí hay cero continua iteracion: FALSE 


#Resultado
# [1] 7 4 1 6 4 2 5 8 3 1 3
```

En este caso se hizo 5 sorteos y nos quedamos con el último `7 4 1 6 4 2 5 8 3 1 3` ya que la variable `check_zero` hace que se quiebre o rompa (`break`) el bucle `while` cuando es falsa.

### Datos de la pregunta

Si se ejecuta el código tal como está (podría re-factorizarse las condicionales por rango en lugar del operador "o" "||") el vector `longlist<-c()` quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
# [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10  2
# [26]  2  2  2  2  2 20 20 20 20 20 20  3  3  3  3  3  3 30 30 30 30 30 30  4  4
# [51]  4  4  4  4 40 40 40 40 40 40  5  5  5  5  5  5 50 50 50 50 50 50  6  6  6
# [76]  6  6  6 60 60 60 60 60 60  7  7  7  7  7 70 70 70 70 70  8  8  8  8  8  8
```

Si `x <- longlist` para el código que se expuso con el bucle `while` se pueden obtener por ejemplo las siguientes permutaciones que no contienen números adyacentes iguales.

```
# Una posible permutacion con números adyacentes diferentes
#  [1]  2  1  2 70  7  1 60  8 50 40 10  5 10  1 60  6  1  4  8  5  1  4 70  1 20
# [26]  5 40  7  8  1 10  5 10  3 30 10  7  8  3 50 20  7 10 70  3  5 40 30  6 20
# [51] 50  4 20 10 40  2  4  1  8  3  1  2 20 30 10 50 40 60 50 60 40  1 30  3 30
# [76]  3  6  4  2  1  6  2 10 60  5 20  8 10 70  6 50  4 60 10 30  6 10  7  1 70


# Otra posible permutacion con números adyacentes diferentes
#  [1]  4  1 40  5 20 60  2 10 20  5 70 50  4  1 10  4  1  2  4 50  4  5  7  3 70
# [26] 60 10  1  5 30  4 70 20  1 50  1 10  2 50  8 30  8 30 40 30 60 20  8 40 10
# [51] 60  7  6  1  7  5  7  6  3 30  6  8 10  3 40 30 10 20  1 10  1 20  8  6  2
# [76] 70  3 10 70  7 50  6  1 60  5  2 40  3 10  6  2  8 10 50  1 40  1 10 60  3
```

Pero como se mencionó al inicio dependerá de los datos de entrada y su tamaño para verificar que exista una permutación con números adyacentes diferentes.

### Sobre complejidad

Existen algoritmos recursivos que dan todas las posibles combinaciones... inclusive en el [proyecto euler problema 24](https://projecteuler.net/problem=24) se pide hallar todas las permutaciones de `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` es:

```
print(factorial(10)) # 3628800  # mas de tres millones
```

Acá lo que se ha hecho es un muestreo de las posibles combinaciones de interés sin tener que generar todas las posibles permutaciones `print(factorial(100))  # 9.332622e+157` este concepto se emplea en *minibatch* para entrenamiento de machine learning (aprendizaje automático - AA) así como las permutaciones como tal a una base de datos (específicamente a sus indices) en dicha área.

> **Las aplicaciones prácticas en Aprendizaje Automático me hicieron contestar esta pregunta que al día de hoy lleva casi 4 años formulada.**