# Variables aleatorias discretas y graficar su función de probabilidad acumulada en R

Tags: r, random, packages

En este post se comentó sobre como generar [Números aleatorios con probabilidades distintas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235990/n%C3%BAmeros-aleatorios-con-probabilidades-distintas/236296#236296)

Sé que R provee una función [sample](http://www.rexamples.com/14/Sample()) para obtener una muestra con y sin reposición para un conjunto de datos.

En tal sentido, sería sencillo escribir lo siguiente para mezclar todos los datos contenidos en `dat` con sus respectivas probabilidades `prob`

```
dat <- c(5,10,25,50,80)
prob <- c(0.6299994, 0.2998997, 0.0699999, 0.0001000, 0.0000010)

sample(dat, prob=prob) # size=3 obtendríamos 3 de los 5 números
```

He buscado sin éxito encontrar un `package` que permita gráficar las funciones de probabilidad sin reposición, no sé si alguien conozca alguna ya implementada.

Por ejemplo que grafique las probabilidad acumuladas de

```
sample(1:9)
```

Conforme se van extrayendo los números -sin reposición- quedando algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A pesar de no haber encontrar algo ya hecho para usar directamente, pude hacer una implementación sobre el particular.

```
sinReposicion <- function (x=1:10, p, n=F, g=F){
    if (missing(p)) { s<- length(x); p <- rep(1/s,s)}
    if (!n) {n <- length(x)}

    n <- min(n,length(x)) # la muestra no puede ser mayor
                          # a la cantidad de datos
    dat <- c()            # contenedor de datos a extraidos

    dm <- min(as.integer(round(sqrt(n),0)),3)   # dimensiones del grid máximo 3x3
    par(mfrow=c(dm,dm))                         # combinar graficos dmxdm

    for (j in 1:n){
        pA <- c(p[1], 0)    # longitud 2 como minimo
                            # pA seria de longitud 1 cuando el tamanio de
                            # muestra sea igual a los datos por tanto
                            # para que trabaje el siguiente bucle 'for' se debe
                            # garantizar que siempre hay un elemento anterior en
                            # el vector pA que contiene las probabilidades Acum

        for ( i in 2:max( length(p), 2 ) ) pA[i] <- p[i]+pA[i-1]

        if (g){
                if (j==n) pA<-pA[1] # tiene que haber solo una probabilidad 

                plot(   c(0,x), c(0,pA),
                        col=rgb(243,182,65, max=255),
                        col.main="azure4", col.lab="azure4",

                        cex.axis = 1, cex.lab = 1, type="s", xaxt="n",

                        main=paste0("En Extraccion ",j),
                        ylab="Probabilidad Acumulada",
                        xlab="Número de Interés"
                    )

                box(col="white")
                axis(side=1, at=c(0,x), col="azure4", col.axis="azure4", col.ticks="azure4")
                axis(side=2, col="azure4", col.axis="azure4", col.ticks="azure4")
        }

        a <- runif(1,0,1)           # se genera un número aleatorio entre 0 y 1
        id <- min( which( rank(pA)>a & pA>a ) ) # se determina 
        dat <- c(dat, x[id])        # x[id] es equivalente a x[pA>a][1]

        x <- x[-id]; p <- p[-id]    # retiramos el dato y
                                    # la probabilidad correspondiente

        p <- p/sum(p)               # actualizamos las probabilidades
                                    # de los elementos que quedan
                                    # para que todas sumen 1
    }

    dat
}
```

Puedes probar el código en [replit](https://repl.it/repls/CommonTransparentScientificcomputing)

Mi consulta como dije es si ya existe un paquete que realice este tipo de cosas porque deduzco que estos, trabajan llamando a C y son más rápidos por ende.

```
debug   / funciones            sample         sinReposicion
Real time:                     0.225 s           0.254 s
User time:                     0.147 s           0.176 s
Sys. time:                     0.080 s           0.077 s
CPU share:                     101.34 %          99.78 %
```

Los valores arriba señalados pueden variar cuando los ejecutes

sample [Try It Online - TIO](https://tio.run/##LY1LCoAwDET3nqLLFqKkYmsDehh/C8EftfeviRqY8CaBmZjzPCTVlWrSDixC7cAhBDTFFc/xe2Dla@JpQGHFFIhaQfRypRcRLetHMabghPVI@h72a1s014CSzF6WMTk/)

sinReposicion [Try It Online - TIO](https://tio.run/##VVHbTsMwDH3vVxghoVgkW1KxsY5u0l74AF6rPZR23QJrEvUiKqF9e3HSCkGUyznOsWPHzTi22rydnG11oa2BVEDVm6LzmA07tVWSO252r/gdAegKWK1bcjkzhwjfbSquJ3PuLmzAF3CpaE6OqWXLW7zN@jtDOvNH5y@I19oww3@tSNYy71JRMATCNCvbAPsAbUBtTXgfwB28wmXqyCXCPVytOeuuLyGGwtYWKKqubZAGd@3d422dD2x@yiGPKXV3yPQxFY72R4@FOgavsOVUSG90xRSXXGGw6XLK@euiiwtrcvPJ3AH3OTxQrH2Ok2ougQ4@ZLo8YhTMQyqGTBAPn@QCnOohtmz7mtIifps@IbpFER2@GQVbcWpBvOIryTcSI9fY9@lCLtZxQuOJg1wQ2iTJs4dy7a1JgFIqWjP0hPJxjTYd@9d26rTP2O18dMRx/AE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como el código en si mismo genera los gráficos y dado que no he tenido éxito en encontrar un paquete que obtenga lo solicitado, sólo puedo indicar que el código publicado inicialmente puede ser simplificado con la función `cumsum`

En tal sentido, se puede reemplazar estas sentencias:

```
pA <- c(p[1], 0)  
for ( i in 2:max( length(p), 2 ) ) pA[i] <- p[i]+pA[i-1]
```

Por esta otra:

```
pA <- cumsum(p)
```

Si bien no se gana mucho rendimiento

```
debug / funciones    sinReposicion / cumsum
Real time:                  0.244 s
User time:                  0.193 s
Sys. time:                  0.050 s
CPU share:                  99.65 %
Exit code:                  0
```

*Los valores arriba señalados pueden variar cuando los ejecutes* [Try It Online - TIO](https://tio.run/##VVHLboMwELzzFdtLtZZMYkdNGlISKZd@QK9RD5RHcFsWC4OKFOXb6dpEUYsMnp0dPGO7myZn6K20rTO5aQnSGKqB8t5jHPd6p5W0kvav4hIBmAqwMY5/OaMVAi4ujb9LOvc1juIFbBp3pUW9dNKJ603/QKyjPzrf4LoxhCTvrGC2yPo0zlEAYx5V2wF@giHQOwr@APbIiqFxQ8MBAhM@GTsPZCrUUkk9N0wxm/zUJq@xy@gL7VEcMnjkVQ6ZmFU3T57keDLFu4gCPabxeIq5DruyAc4BuFre7a9z6ugaRTz508txLfnMVmu5VnKrRGS79mNuqMVmlfDzJEEtGG2T5NlDtfFsEqBSmt8b9AXnsZ2hHv/dE1@NT2z3fnUhpukX)

Por lo menos se simplifica código, sin que se pierda lo alcanzado.